# How to pass parameter for Kodein Injected instances?

Tags: kotlin, kodein

In Kodein, when I have the below binding

```
    bind<AppDependent>() with singleton {
        AppDependent("abc", instance(), instance())
    }
```

I could get my appDependent using below

```
private val appDependent : AppDependent by instance(
```

However if I like to provide the `title` as below

```
    bind<AppDependent>() with multiton {
        title: String -> AppDependent(title, instance(), instance())
    }
```

How could I create `appDependent`?

I tried something as below but not working.

```
private val appDependent : AppDependent by instance("Main")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that we could do it as below

```
private val appDependent: AppDependent by instance(arg = "My Text")
```

Comment: You can also use it with complex objects like data classes